# Serializing Multiple Objects to a File in PHP, can't unserialize?

Tags: php, serialization

Using PHP 5.3.8.

I'm attempting to implement two functions, `save($adoption)` which serializes an `Adoption` instance, appends a delimiter, then appends it to the end of a text file, and `loadAdoptions()`, which opens the text file, `explode()`s the contents on the delimiter, and `unserialize()`s each object in a for loop through the contents of the array `explode()` returned then calls `Display()` on them.

Here's the shortest form reproducing my problem:

```
<html><head><title>Request Processed</title></head><body>
<?php
class Dog {
    var $name; 
}

class Adoption
{
    var $dog;

    function Display()
    {
        echo $dog->name;
    }
}

function save($adoption)
{
    file_put_contents("../adoptions/adoptions.txt", (serialize($adoption)."<!-- E -->"));
 }

function loadAdoptions()
{
    $filename = '../adoptions/adoptions.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
        $datain = file_get_contents($filename);
        $out = explode("<!-- E -->", $datain);

        echo "<br /><u>Retrieved Data</u><br />";
        $count = count($out);
        echo 'Count: '.$count;

        for ($i = 0; i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $curAdoption = unserialize($out[i]);
           if (curAdoption)
                echo $curAdoption->Display();
            else
                echo 'Error Reading Record.';
            echo '<br />';
        }

    }
}

$newDog = new Dog();
$newDog->name = "Scruffles";
$newAdoption = new Adoption();
$newAdoption->dog = newDog;
save(newAdoption);
loadAdoptions();
?>
</body></html>
```

On line 38, where `Display()` is called, `Fatal error: Call to a member function Display() on a non-object`

Comment: Please post your code ***here***, not on some third party side.

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter doesn't appear anywhere in the serialized version of the object?

Comment: @deceze My Apologies, I thought since it was a relatively large sample, it may be more courteous to host it somewhere else instead of dumping it all here.

Comment: @rdlowrey Yes, I've opened the txt to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few times, you've missed the `$` off the front of a variable. Also to access a class's member variable from a method (getting dog's name in `Display()` you need to use `$this->dog`.

Working source:

```
<html><head><title>Request Processed</title></head><body>
<?php
class Dog {
    var $name; 
}

class Adoption
{
    var $dog;

    function Display()
    {
        echo $this->dog->name;
    }
}

function save($adoption)
{
    file_put_contents("../adoptions/adoptions.txt", (serialize($adoption)."<!-- E -->"));
 }

function loadAdoptions()
{
    $filename = '../adoptions/adoptions.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
        $datain = file_get_contents($filename);
        $out = explode("<!-- E -->", $datain);

        echo "<br /><u>Retrieved Data</u><br />";
        $count = count($out);
        echo 'Count: '.$count;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $curAdoption = unserialize($out[$i]);
           if ($curAdoption)
                echo $curAdoption->Display();
            else
                echo 'Error Reading Record.';
            echo '<br />';
        }

    }
}

$newDog = new Dog();
$newDog->name = "Scruffles";
$newAdoption = new Adoption();
$newAdoption->dog = $newDog;
save($newAdoption);
loadAdoptions();
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This reads the first correctly for me, but fails on the second record.
EG:  
    `Retrieved Data`  
    `Count: 2`  
   `Scruffles`  
    `Error Reading Record.`  
Produces the same output no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: Because the second record is empty, it's not saved into the text file - the contents of adoptions.txt is: `O:8:"Adoption":1:{s:3:"dog";O:3:"Dog":1:{s:4:"name";s:9:"Scruffles";}}<!-- E -->` - that's one serialized object plus your delimiter. When you explode on `<!-- E -->` you get two elements returns; one is your object, the other is the empty space after it.

Comment: But the second time the script is run, another object should be appended before display is called, however, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `file_put_contents` overwrites, it doesn't append. If you want it to append, add a third parameter of `FILE_APPEND`: `file_put_contents("../adoptions/adoptions.txt", (serialize($adoption)."<!-- E -->"), FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I apologize, that was a rather large oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

`$curAdoption` does not have a method `Display()`...

Comment: Which means it's not an `Adoption` class, which means `unserialize()` is failing, but why?